# Paypal Payment Method Missing from Backend Order

Tags: admin, orders, paypal, ce-1.9.0.1, backend

I have Paypal Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution set up on a multi-store Magento installation.

Paypal works fine in the front end, but when I try to do a backend order it says: "No Payment Methods".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that not all payment methods are designed to be used both on the frontend and backend of Magento.

It could be that in this case this payment method only works in the frontend of Magento.

Checking the source code for class **Mage_Paypal_Model_Hostedpro** I found this:

`protected $_canUseInternal = false;`, this bit indicates that cannot be used for backend orders, its also not available for Multishipping orders.

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking on Pablos answer you could activate that by setting that flag to true (recommended to build out a module to do so).

I believe the intended functionality is to allow the frontend user (customer) to use their Paypal account, thus the disabling of the admin view as your sales agents will probably not have access to their Paypal account.  Are you using HostedPro as your Credit Card processor as well?  That would be the only use case that would functionally require using the Paypal on account of a customer.

You may have to do some additional work on the blocks as well.

Comment: I don't believe that setting that value to true will help because the Paypal payment method implementation requires the customer to login with their account which isn't applicable to backend orders.